# Text into sliding window and count

Tags: awk

I have file (More than 1 lack lines)as like this

```
 20     14370   rs6054257 G      A       29   PASS   NS=3;DP=14;AF=0.5;DB;H2           GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:48:1:51,51 
 20     17330   .         T      A       3    q10    NS=3;DP=11;AF=0.017               GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:49:3:58,50 
 20     1110696 rs6040355 A      G,T     67   PASS   NS=2;DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;AA=T;DB GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:21:6:23,27
 20     1230237 .         T      .       47   PASS   NS=3;DP=13;AA=T                   GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:54:7:56,60
 20     1234567           GTC    G,GTCT  50   PASS   NS=3;DP=9;AA=G                    GT:GQ:DP    0/1:35:4
```

I need split as sliding window and count "0/0" positions as like this

```
 Pos     Count 
 1-10001  0
 2-10002  1
 3-10003  0
```

For counting each 10000 positions I used this cmd

```
tail -n +11 file | 
awk -v n=10000 '/0\/0/{c++} NR%n==0{print c; c=0} END {if (NR%n!=0) print c}'
```

Comment: Sorry but its not clear. Could you please do mention more details like how is your expected output is coming(logic of getting it) in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Completely based on your shown attempts only, written in GNU `awk`. Couldn't test much since samples are not having 0/0 values in it, should work through. Taken `tail` command from OP's attempt itself.

```
tail -n +11 Input_file | 
awk -v n="10000" '
  NR%n==0{
    ++occur
    print n+occur,count
    count=""
  }
  /0\/0/{
    count++
  }
  END{
    ++occur
    if(count){ print n+occur }
  }
'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you have multiple occurrences of `0/0` in your lines and you want to count all in each line then try following slightly different from 1st solution.

```
tail -n +11 Input_file | 
awk -v n="10000" '
  NR%n==0{
    ++occur
    print n+occur,count
    count=""
  }
  {
    count+=gsub(/0\/0/,"&")
  }
  END{
    ++occur
    if(count){ print n+occur }
  }
'
```