# Sed and count awk

Tags: awk

I need to split a text file as a sliding window and need to count “0/0” from each segment.

For example If I have 20 lines of files and window size is 10 the command as follows

```
sed -n '1,11p' input.txt |grep -c "0/0"
sed -n '2,12p' input.txt |grep -c "0/0"
sed -n '3,13p' input.txt |grep -c "0/0"
.
.
.
sed -n '8,18p' input.txt |grep -c "0/0"
sed -n '9,19p' input.txt |grep -c "0/0"
```

But if I have a large file this method wont help me to do the same. Is there any way to automate this ?

Comment: Sed does no math, so there's no easy way imho to come up with a sed-only solution. Probably awk would be enough instead. However, the commends you wrote are counting the number of lines (out of the 10 lines) matching `0/0`; if there's more than one `0/0` on a line, that counts as 1, not 2. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Also could you please do let us know if `window size` 10 and total lines in Input_file is always given to us(asking if we could pass this to program)?

Comment: Yes window size and total number lines we can input

Comment: _I need to split a text file - - and need to count “0/0” from each segment_ Please show sample data from the said file `input.txt` to get a better understanding of the structure and to use for testing. Also, please show the expected output. Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463282/split-as-sliding-window-and-count and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443800/text-into-sliding-window-and-count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v k=11 -v str="0/0" '{
  cnt += found[NR%k] = index($0,str)>=1;
}
NR>=k {
  print 1+NR-k "-" NR, cnt+0;
  cnt -= found[(NR+1)%k];
}' file
```

This calls window size `k`. Output prints a line number range and how many of those lines contained the string `str` (matched using `index` to avoid regex matching).